# How to show registration page in another language in Drupal 7, maintaining its natural behaviour?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I need to show my registration page in another language, keeping this separate from his natural behaviour. 
In particular this page must be showed in English on the page of the site it owns to, but i need to show it in Italian on another site into an iframe.
Now, common sense tells me i need a page

```
www.example.com/user
```

and a

```
www.example.com/it/user
```

and i tried to achieve this by "admin/config/regional/language/configure" and the option "Determine the language from the URL (Path prefix or domain)." and all works fine, but, for some reason, as i activate this option, ALL my site pages get a "/en/" in their url, breaking a lot of things into the site (that is extremely complex).
There's a way to achieve this behaviour for the registration page only? (be able to call a page www.example.com/it/user to show registration in italian and having www.example.com/user and all other pages in the site work without any changes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be a small custom module.

Pros:

- Easy to tweak and install
- Lightweight, code based so you can just check it into VCS and deploy
- Can be extended for other language sets

Cons:

- Not scaleable.
- Requires a dev if you want to change the text

.info file:

```
name = User Registration Languages
description = Alter the user registration form to present alternative translations
core = 7.x
```

.module file

```
<?php

/**
 * implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()
 * https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7
 *
 * @param $form
 * @param $state
 */
function userreglang_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$state) {

  // the arg() function returns a path component (zero based index)
  // https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7
  // in this case we're looking for:
  // user/register/{language_arg} e.g user/register/it
  $lang = arg(2);

  // uncomment the following if you want take a look at the form array prior to modification
  // be sure to  temporarily give the anonymous user role the ability to "Access developer information"
  /*if(module_exists('devel')) {
    dpm($form);
  } // */

  if($lang && $map = _userreglang_languages($lang)) {
    $form['account']['name']['#title'] = $map['name'];
    $form['account']['name']['#description'] = $map['name_desc'];
    $form['account']['mail']['#title'] = $map['mail'];
    $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = $map['mail_desc'];
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = $map['button'];
  }

  // uncomment the following if you want take a look at the form array after modification
  /*if(module_exists('devel')) {
    dpm($form);
  } // */
}


/**
 * helper function for different language maps you might have for the user registration form
 *
 * @param $lang
 * @return array|null
 */
function _userreglang_languages($lang) {

  $map = [
    'it' => [
      'name'      => 'Your name, yo!',
      'name_desc' => 'Input your username fool!',
      'mail'      => 'Email, you gots it?',
      'mail_desc' => 'Seriously do you not know what email is?',
      'button'    => 'Click it baby!',
    ]
  ];

  if(isset($map[$lang])) {
    return $map[$lang];
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you very much!! The declaration of the variable $map was wrong according to php compiler. I had to correct it and i added the correction to your answer for those who will come next.

Comment: It seem that adding a syntactic correction does not make the answer 'more readable' according to peer review and my correction was rejected. I put it here: 
  $map['it']['name'] = 'Your name, yo!';
  $map['it']['name_desc'] = 'Input your username fool!';
  $map['it']['mail'] = 'Email, you gots it?';
  $map['it']['mail_desc'] = 'Seriously do you not know what email is?';
  $map['it']['name'] = 'Click it baby!';

Answer (score 0):

On drupal.stackoverflow i got a simpler answer. Here it is:

Navigate to /admin/config/regional/language within your site, and verify these things (and correct where appropriate):

Use "English" as your default language
use the "Edit" link for "English" on that page, which will bring you to "/admin/config/regional/language/edit/en". On that page, make sure the value for "Path prefix language code" is "blank".

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163754/how-to-show-registration-page-in-another-language-in-drupal-7-maintaining-its-n